# Solana-SDK and Solana-Client doesn't work as a dependencies

Tags: cargo, solana-sdk, solana-client

Hello I am trying desperately to use solana-sdk and solana-client but when I do cargo build-bpf it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

[image]

If I specify only solana-client and solana-sdk, I get this error:

[image]

Here is a capture that shows the versions I have of solana, cargo , rustup, rustc

[image]

Comment: hey can u specify why do u want to use RpcClient inside your on-chain programs

Comment: Hello, i need to use this, for make somme verification, for example, when a user create a pseudo, else , he have only this pseudo and not othersusers. For implement this off chain it's easy but on chain it difficult when solana-sdk doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand this , can u put it in a proper context with an example

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your solana cli to stable 1.13.4
And also in your smart contract (on chain) programs you are suppose to use
solana-program library.
solana-sdk and solana-client are for client side libraries

Comment: Hello, i tried with 1.13.4 it doesn't work, i tried now with 1.14.9, i get this errors

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys` when i compile

Comment: The answer says to not use `solana-client` and `solana-sdk` in your on-chain program, and to use `solana-program` instead. You need to delete the other dependencies and use `solana-program` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use use " solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient " , its possible only with solana_client. How i can do ?